# OpenBSD 6.6 wlan DHCP no link, routing issues

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp, ifconfig, openbsd

I've been bashing my head against this for a few days so I'm asking for help.

The machine is a Thinkpad using a Intel PRO 2100 wifi card with the ipw driver (https://man.openbsd.org/ipw).
I tried using another card before with the iwi driver but it kept outputting firmware error so I switched.

I have managed to connect to my WPA2 secured network but Im not getting further and DHCP (dhclient ipw0 or sh /etc/netstart) keeps outputting the message after timeout:
No link........ sleeping.

I have configured my ifconfig through the /etc/hostname.ipw0 file as advised in the manual, my config is as follows.

```
nwid hotspot wpakey password chan up wpaprotos wpa2 

inet 10.220.1.156 255.255.255.0
dhcp
```

This results in "ifconfig ipw0" outputting this

```
ipw0: flags=808843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,AUTOCONF4> mtu 1500
    lladdr 00:0c:f1:24:1c:2a
    index 1 priority 4 llprio 3
    groups: wlan
    media: IEEE802.11 autoselect (DS11 mode 11b)
    status: active
    ieee80211: nwid hotspot chan 7 bssid 30:23:03:1a:4c:7a -18dBm wpakey wpaprotos wpa2 wpaakms psk wpaciphers ccmp wpagroupcipher ccmp
    inet 10.220.1.156 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.220.1.255
```

I have also added this to my rc.conf as I was advised here (https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/solved-re0-no-link-giving-up-my-card-driver-or-dhcp-server-problem.4566/)

```
ifconfig_ipw0="DCHP"
```

This is where I get stuck, dhcp still timeouts and gives me the error message, im able to ping 10.220.1.156 but no other ip from the router, this make me believe the issues is to be solved with the route command, "route show" outputs this.

```
Internet
        Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu  Interface
        10.220.1/24        10.220.1.156       Cn         0        0     -     8 ipw0 
        10.220.1.156       00:0c:f1:24:1c:2a  UHLl       0        0     -     1 ipw0 
        10.220.1.255       10.220.1.156       Hb         0        0     -     1 ipw0
```

What is known that the network is named "hotspot" passworded with "password", its gateway is "10.220.1.1"

As this is my first post I am unable to comment on replies, John suggests me to use another wifi card as some are not "whitelisted" as brought up here http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card
But this is only a BIOS whitelist and the combo I'm using is confirmed to be working on the thinkpads forum and the card is gathered from another IBM machine and is whitelisted. So does my routing look OK?

I read this post on serverfault and thought I might have to do something similar. https://serverfault.com/a/581162

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select ‘‘I need to merge user profiles’’ to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/1114413/c-c-c-c and https://superuser.com/users/1114482/c-c-c-c.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question without needing to have your edits reviewed and approved.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an older Intel Card, and certainly some Lenovo (and IBM) Thinkpads did not allow "foreign" cards to be installed. Try a USB Card that is modern and that should easily work.